# MySQL Update on duplicate error

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, EVENTS and EVENT_ATTENDEES.

I'd like to be able to attempt a row insert on event_attendees and if the call_sign and event_id already exist in the table, it should update the response for that row instead of inserting a new one.

**Events Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `event_type` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `event_name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `event_start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `event_end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `max_attendees` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `open_registration` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) 
ALTER TABLE `events`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`);

ALTER TABLE `events`
  MODIFY `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11
```

**Event Attendees**

```
CREATE TABLE `event_attendees` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `call_sign` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `response` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) 

ALTER TABLE `event_attendees`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `event_id_2` (`event_id`,`call_sign`),
  ADD KEY `event_id` (`event_id`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `event_attendees`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;

ALTER TABLE `event_attendees`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `event_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`event_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

I have tried the below query, but constantly get an error (I have created an event that has event_id = 10):

```
INSERT INTO event_attendees
   (event_id, call_sign, response)
VALUES
   ('10', '007', 'Declined')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   response = VALUES('Declined')
```

" #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test')' at line 6"

Comment: Edit your question and show the complete text of the error message.

Comment: Actually, ```VALUES('Declined')``` should be ```VALUES(`response`)``` - use backticks for column and table names. If you want the value to be 'Declined' in the update, use ```'Declined'``` without the VALUE function

Comment: The error message doesn't match with the query. test') isn't in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of `VALUES` here. Modify your query as:

```
INSERT INTO event_attendees
   (event_id, call_sign, response)
VALUES
   ('10', '007', 'Declined')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   response = 'Declined'
```

From doc:

> you can use the VALUES(col_name) function to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) you can find more about `VALUES` function.